# OpenEdge SQL DBA Account Setup

Tags: openedge

I'm setting up SQL access in a newly created OpenEdge 11.5 database.

In checking the contents of the sysdbauth table using "select * from sysprogress.sysdbauth", I see that there are two users setup by default:  sysprogress and a user with the name of the Linux user account that was used to create the database.

I'm looking for recommendations as to how to handle these two accounts.  Obviously I want to have an account to use for DBA tasks.  Should I use one of these accounts for the purpose?  If so, what should I do with the other account?

Is it possible (and safe) to be deleting either of these predefined accounts?

Answer (score 2):

On page 175 of the [Database Administration guide](http://documentation.progress.com/output/OpenEdge115/pdfs/dmadm/dmadm.pdf) you can read about default users and why they are created:

> **Tables used from SQL only**
>
> An SQL database administrator (DBA) is a person assigned a sysdbauth record in the database.
>   SQL DBAs have access to all meta data and data in the database. To support internal schema
>   caching, every OpenEdge database begins with a DBA defined as "sysprogress." However,
>   OpenEdge restricts the use of "sysprogress."
>   When you create an OpenEdge database using the PROCOPY or PRODB commands, and the
>   database does not have any _User records defined (from the source database, for example), then
>   a DBA is automatically designated with the login ID of the person who creates the database. This
>   person can log into the database and use the GRANT statement to designate additional SQL DBAs,
>   and use the CREATE USER and DROP USER statements to add and delete user IDs.When creating
>   users, this DBA can also specify users as SQL-only users, who can only access the database
>   through SQL.

There are several knowledge base entries around the task of deleting or disabling the default users.

http://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/P5094
http://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/P161411

This suggests that it's really safe to delete or disable these accounts but you should:

1) Create replacing accounts first.

2) As always: test in a separate environment first and not in production!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in fact Progress kind of expects you to do so. Create a root account and get rid of both. It's fine.